# How to create multiple Json files with different values

Tags: python, json, linux, powershell

I want to generate multiple (thousands) json files (to be sent as post body in different requests) with different values but same keys. Can someone please help me how I can do this. If there is any shell script for the same, that will be helpful. Below is the sample json file and I want to change values for 'Key9' and 'key10'.

```
{
    "Key1": [
        "value1"
    ],
    "key9": "value9",
    "key10": "value10",
    "Key2": {
        "Key3": "value3"
    },
    "key4": key4,
    "currency": "USD",
    "Key5": [
        {
            "key6": 0,
            "key7": 2,
            "key8": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What language are you using? The simplest way to make the changes you are considering is to have a script in the language you are using to generate your json files, where you programmatically set the values you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to have a template file and replace the markers with the values you want to have.

E.g.

Let's say you have this file

```
{
   id: "{{ID_KEY}}"
}
```

You can do like this:

```
search_text = "{{ID_KEY}}"

replace_text = "MY_ID"
  
with open(r'template.txt', 'r') as template_file:
    data = template_file.read().replace(search_text, replace_text)
  
with open(r'result.txt', 'w') as result_file:
    result_file.write(data)
```